# glDrawElements to draw a cube in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I recently started to learn OpenGL through Python thanks to several tutorial (especially the Nicolas P. Rougier one: http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/opengl/).

I am now switching to 3D and I am trying to draw a cube.

Thus, I manage to get some triangles which do not render a cube (this seems to be normal as I do not duplicate my vertices and I use the glDrawArrays function).

However, after, I build an index "vector" to further use the glDrawElements function to render my cube. As a result, I do not get any error but nothing appears on screen.

I hope you could be of some help!

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.GLUT as glut

vertex_code = """

    uniform float scale;
    uniform mat4 matCam;
    attribute vec4 color;
    attribute vec3 position;
    varying vec4 v_color;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = matCam*vec4(scale*position, 1.0);
        v_color = color;
    } """

fragment_code = """
    varying vec4 v_color;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = v_color;
    } """

def display():
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    #gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12)

    gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, len(index), gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, index) # render nothing (i.e. only the background color)
    glut.glutSwapBuffers()

def reshape(width,height):
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

def keyboard( key, x, y ):
    if key == '\033':
        sys.exit( )

def timer(fps):
    global clock
    clock += 0.0005*1000.0/fps
    print(clock)
#    eye = np.array([0,0,1])
#    center = np.array([0,clock,0])
#    up = np.array([0,1,0])
#    mat = computeLookAtMatrix(eye, center, up)
    theta = clock;
    mat = np.array([[np.cos(theta), 0, np.sin(theta), 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0],
                [-np.sin(theta), 0, np.cos(theta), 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "matCam")
    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, False, mat)



    glut.glutTimerFunc(1000/fps, timer, fps)
    glut.glutPostRedisplay()


# GLUT init
# --------------------------------------
glut.glutInit()
glut.glutInitDisplayMode(glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | glut.GLUT_RGBA)
glut.glutCreateWindow('Hello world!')
glut.glutReshapeWindow(512,512)
glut.glutReshapeFunc(reshape)
glut.glutDisplayFunc(display)
glut.glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard)
glut.glutTimerFunc(1000/60, timer, 60)

# Build data
# --------------------------------------
data = np.zeros(8, [("position", np.float32, 3),
                    ("color",    np.float32, 4)])

data['color']    = [ (1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1), (1,1,0,1),
                    (1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1), (1,1,0,1) ]

data['position'] = [ (-1,-1,1),
                     (1,-1,1),
                        (1,1,1),   
                        (-1,1,1),
                        (-1,-1,-1),
                        (1,-1,-1),
                        (1,1,-1),
                        (-1,1,-1)]

index = np.array([0,1,2,
                2,3,0,
                1,5,6,
                6,2,1,
                7,6,5,
                5,4,7,
                4,0,3,
                3,7,4,
                4,5,1,
                1,0,4,
                3,2,6,
                6,7,3])

# Build & activate program
# --------------------------------------

# Request a program and shader slots from GPU
program  = gl.glCreateProgram()
vertex   = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
fragment = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

# Set shaders source
gl.glShaderSource(vertex, vertex_code)
gl.glShaderSource(fragment, fragment_code)

# Compile shaders
gl.glCompileShader(vertex)
gl.glCompileShader(fragment)

# Attach shader objects to the program
gl.glAttachShader(program, vertex)
gl.glAttachShader(program, fragment)

# Build program
gl.glLinkProgram(program)

# Get rid of shaders (no more needed)
gl.glDetachShader(program, vertex)
gl.glDetachShader(program, fragment)

# Make program the default program
gl.glUseProgram(program)


# Build buffer
# --------------------------------------

# Request a buffer slot from GPU
buffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)

# Make this buffer the default one
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)

# Upload data
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.nbytes, data, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

# same for index buffer
buffer_index= gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_index)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index.nbytes, index, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)


# Bind attributes
# --------------------------------------
stride = data.strides[0]
offset = ctypes.c_void_p(0)
loc = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, "position")
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)

offset = ctypes.c_void_p(data.dtype["position"].itemsize)
loc = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, "color")
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 4, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)

gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_index)

# Bind uniforms
# --------------------------------------
loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "scale")
gl.glUniform1f(loc, 0.5)
clock = 0

loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "matCam")
print(loc)
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, False, np.eye(4))

# Enter mainloop
# --------------------------------------
glut.glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, len(index), gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, index)
```

The index argument has two different meanings depending on whether an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound or not:

- If no bound: Then it specifies a pointer to client memory where the indices are stored
- If a `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound, then the index parameter specifies an offset into this buffer. This defines where in the buffer the indices start.

In your case, a buffer is bound, so you tell OpenGL to start somewhere in the buffer. But what you want is to start at the beginning of the buffer, thus you have to set index to 0.

```
gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, len(index), gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
```

Comment: I replace (GLvoid *)0 by ctypes.c_void_p(0) (or None) and it's (almost) work as I only get half a square. It is strange as I retrieve the vertices and indices from an existing tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, forgot you were using python.

Comment: Why do I only get half a square?

Comment: I solve the problem adding dtype=np.uint32 in my numpy index array.